# Integrating Spring with GWT

Tags: java, spring, gwt

I have a modular Spring project with the following Maven modules: Persistence, Service and Controller (there is also a Spring web app module).

I wonder, how to integrate Spring with GWT. Do I need to implement a GWT controller, like in [this post](http://technophiliac.wordpress.com/2008/08/24/giving-gwt-a-spring-in-its-step/)? If so, should this controller and my existing one be both in a separate module?

Well, it's probably the whole description of my a little bit abstract question. I'd really appreciate if someone could share the related expirience. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In my past experience, GWT really wants you to build your application around it. "Just plugging it in" to an existing system is likely to be tricky. Also, I think GWT has hooks to make it nicer to integrate with Guice (vs. Spring) for DI.

Comment: @HankGay Thanks for the comment, I'll think about that.

Comment: I realize it's not much of an answer if you can't adjust things right now, but I hope it really was useful. If you're too late in the game to change things right now, then maybe https://technophiliac.wordpress.com/2008/08/24/giving-gwt-a-spring-in-its-step/ can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [RestyGWT](http://restygwt.fusesource.org/). We use it in combinations with Spring controllers, too.

Comment: Thanks, I'll regard this possibility.